# SignalR /signalr/hubs 403 Not found on MVC 5 Application (Individual user accounts authentication)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I have created the MVC 5 Web Application based on individual user authentication.

I have read in the asp.net article
 http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc shows no need to create startup.cs seperately for individual user authentication type application.
So i added the **app.MapSignalR();** inside the ConfigureAuth  Method reside in the  **App_Start>Startup.Auth.cs** file.

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {           
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });           app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        app.MapSignalR();}
```

In view page i added the following reference

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

But in run time i get the 403 Not found error for /Signalr/hubs js file.
How to resolve it.

Comment: did you turn off Form Authentication when using OWIN authentication? It could be that the Form authentication module intercepts the request before the OWIN and returns 403

Comment: also check if you have a PHYSICAL folder named `signalr`. If so, remove it or move it to another location

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `app.MapSignalR()` is called?

I'm not sure if it should work with this command placed inside ConfigureAuth, but I would try to make a separate startup file as mentioned in the article:

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Try to place it in the separate file and see if it works for you.

Also, does your Application_Start method looks like this?

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

I've found that the order in which you are calling registration methods is important so ensure that you have placed them correctly and that you have that `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()` method called.

Comment: RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() is obsolete in MVC 5.it throws an compilation error when u put inside the  application_start() method.

Comment: That tutorial shows no need to create separate startup.cs file.when u select the individual user authentication

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and it works.

Here is my sample application

cshtml file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        debugger;
        var chat = $.connection.signalhub;
        chat.client.Send = function (msg) {
            debugger;
            $("#message").append(msg);
        }

        $("#btnSend").click(function () {
            debugger;
            chat.server.broadcastMessage($("#txtmessage").val());
            $('#txtmessage').val('').focus();
        });

        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
<div class="row" id="message">

</div>
<input type="text" name="txtmessage" id="txtmessage" />
<button name="btnSend" id="btnSend">Send</button>
```

Here is my SignalRHub

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace SignalR.Code
{
    [HubName("signalhub")]
    public class SignalRHub : Hub
    {
        public void BroadcastMessage(string message)
        {            
            Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Startup.Auth.cs file

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;

namespace SignalR
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });

            app.MapSignalR();

            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I would suggest to check which version of JQuery you used and have you define that anywhere is your project?